# can I do this binary search using the STL?

Tags: c++, stl

I am trying to refactor some code that doesn't use the STL to use the generic algorithms it provide.
I have a struct like this :

```
struct A {
int i;
//other stuff...
};
// ...
A* array; // array of A objects, sorted by A::i member
int n = ...; // array size
```

there is then a function that was coded that takes `A`, `n` and an integer `k`, whose purpose is to give me pointers to to the first and the last element of the array that have their `i` member equal to `k`.

This is implemented by hand in terms of binary search. I was thinking about using `std::equal_range`. The problem is that it requires an object of type A to work, and it forces me to introduce a "dummy" A object with it's `i` member equal to `k`.

Is there a way to do this using the STL, without having to introduce a "dummy" object?
thanks

Comment: Is your range sorted by `i` at all?

Comment: what do you mean "my range"? the array is sorted by i, and I'm trying to get pointers to elements of the array

Comment: The range `[array, array + n)`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Provided your range is sorted according to the value of `A::i`, this is trivially done with a [custom comparator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/equal_range), but note that the comparator must be able compare both ways:

```
struct AComp
{
    bool operator()(int n, A const & a) const { return n < a.i; }
    bool operator()(A const & a, int n) const { return a.i < n; }
};

auto p = std::equal_range(array, array + n, 5, AComp());
```

Now the range `[p.first, p.second)` contains the elements with `A::i` equal to `5`.

The linked page contains more or less exactly this example.

Comment: but how the compiler know that I'm looking to compare 5 (an int) with the A::i member ?

Comment: @lezebulon: Apologies again, I continue getting this wrong. The comparator needs to be able to go both ways, so you have to write your own class. In fact, the linked reference contains precisely your example.

Comment: ok thanks this is very informative, I add no idea I could use several operator() overloads. This is a very subtle use of equal_range... it's a shame this kind of example is not on cplusplus.com ...

Comment: @lezebulon: Argh, the second commenter in 10 minutes to mention that hideous "website" :-) Now here's an argument why it should never be cited or recommended! With the correct reference, your entire question would have evaporated :-S

Comment: yeah I'm aware that the other website is better, but unfortunately google seems to rank it further down the list...

Answer (score 1):

You may also use `std::binary_search()` defined in `<algorithm>` for binary search generally. The prorotype is:

```
template <class ForwardIterator, class T>
  bool binary_search (ForwardIterator first, ForwardIterator last,
                      const T& val);
```

or:

```
template <class ForwardIterator, class T, class Compare>
  bool binary_search (ForwardIterator first, ForwardIterator last,
                      const T& val, Compare comp);
```

Comment: That does something totally different.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a conversion operator(This is more like a hack, I guess)

```
class A
{
    private:
        int i;
    public:
        A(int x) : i(x){}
        operator int(){
            return i;
        }
};
```

If this is done you dont have to define operator< in your struct.