# is this C++ example portable?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, stl

following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18749844/can-i-do-this-binary-search-using-the-stl/18750376) question , I tried to copy paste the example found [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/equal_range) in VS2010 :

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

struct S
{
    int number;
    char name;

    S ( int number, char name  )
        : number ( number ), name ( name )
    {}

    // only the number is relevant with this comparison
    bool operator< ( const S& s ) const
    {
        return number < s.number;
    }
};

struct Comp
{
    bool operator() ( const S& s, int i )
    {
        return s.number < i;
    }

    bool operator() ( int i, const S& s )
    {
        return i < s.number;
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<S> vec = { {1,'A'}, {2,'B'}, {2,'C'}, {2,'D'}, {3,'F'}, {4,'G'} }; //this syntax won't compile in VS2010, so you can leave an empty vector here

    auto p = std::equal_range(vec.begin(),vec.end(),2,Comp());

    for ( auto i = p.first; i != p.second; ++i )
        std::cout << i->name << ' ';
}
```

This will compile fine in release mode, but in debug mode, it will fail to compile.
The reason is that in debug mode, the implementation will check if the iterator range is already sorted, using the given predicate:

```
template<class _FwdIt,
    class _Pr> inline
    void _Debug_order2(_FwdIt _First, _FwdIt _Last, _Pr _Pred,
        _Dbfile_t _File, _Dbline_t _Line, forward_iterator_tag)
    {   // test if range is ordered by predicate, forward iterators
    for (_FwdIt _Next = _First; _First != _Last && ++_Next != _Last; ++_First)
        if (_DEBUG_LT_PRED(_Pred, *_Next, *_First))
            _DEBUG_ERROR2("sequence not ordered", _File, _Line);
    }
```

this ends up calling :

```
template<class _Pr, class _Ty1, class _Ty2> inline
    bool _Debug_lt_pred(_Pr _Pred,
        const _Ty1& _Left, const _Ty2& _Right,
        _Dbfile_t _File, _Dbline_t _Line)
    {   // test if _Pred(_Left, _Right) and _Pred is strict weak ordering
    if (!_Pred(_Left, _Right))
        return (false);
    else if (_Pred(_Right, _Left))
        _DEBUG_ERROR2("invalid operator<", _File, _Line);
    return (true);
    }
```

Except that in my case, no `operator()` can take both left and right "S" argument.
So, is there a bug in the Visual implementation? Or is the original example not supposed to be portable?
I think I could make it work by providing a 3rd operator() overload, but it seems like it should work without

thanks

Comment: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/769370/iterator-debug-version-of-std-equal-range-improperly-handles-predicate

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Nothing in the standard requires the comparator to be callable with two objects from the range. So that is a bug in the standard library used by VS 2010.

Here are all the relevant requirements (quoting C++11):

[lower.bound]§1+2:

> 1 *Requires:* The elements `e` of `[first,last)` shall be partitioned with respect to the expression ...  `comp(e, value)`.
>
> 2 *Returns:* The furthermost iterator `i` in the range `[first,last]` such that for any iterator `j` in the range `[first,i)` the following corresponding conditions hold: ... `comp(*j, value) != false`.

[upper.bound]§1+2:

> 1 *Requires:* The elements `e` of `[first,last)` shall be partitioned with respect to the expression ... `!comp(value, e)`.
>
> 2 *Returns:* The furthermost iterator `i` in the range `[first,last]` such that for any iterator `j` in the range `[first,i)` the following corresponding conditions hold: ... `comp(value, *j) == false`.

[equal.range]§1+2:

> 1 *Requires:* The elements `e` of `[first,last)` shall be partitioned with respect to the expressions ... `comp(e, value)` and `!comp(value, e)`. Also, for all elements `e` of `[first, last)`, ... `comp(e, value)` shall imply `!comp(value, e)`.
>
> 2 *Returns:*
>
> ...
>
> ```
> make_pair(lower_bound(first, last, value, comp),
>           upper_bound(first, last, value, comp))
> ```

(The ellipses are for the non-comparator version).

Comment: +1 great! This also means that the input to `std::equal_range()` doesn't need to be sorted, unlike the test by VS2010. It only needs to be partitioned w.r.t. comparison with `e`.

Comment: @Walter : you're right, I think this is an even bigger issue because there would be cases where you are using equal_range correctly and the VS run time checks would fail

Comment: @lezebulon Yes, it's a bug in VS2010, as Angew has pointed out. At least it crashes at compile time (rather than run-time), so you can fix it by providing an additional comparison operator.

Comment: @Walter Which would be good programming practice anyway.  (And I'd be interesting in seeing a case where you could have a sequence which was correctly partitioned according to `comp`, but was not sorted.)

Comment: @JamesKanze Here is your use case: assume an unsorted range, then  *partition* w.r.t. `x` (and then to call `equal_range`) is **faster than to sort** it first instead.

Answer (score 2):

Angew has already quoted the standard and pointed out that VS is buggy. I merely want to emphasize that **VS2010 has two bugs** here (under debug mode):

1. It tries to use `Compare::operator(_Ty1, _Ty2)` which is not required to exist by the standard. This [known bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/769370/iterator-debug-version-of-std-equal-range-improperly-handles-predicate) has been highlighted by Angew and pointed to by Ben's comment.
2. It tests whether the input range is sorted, which is not required by the standard either.
   This is a far more serious bug, as it reduces the usability of `equal_range` and in the worst case requires a full sort of the range, even if that was not necessary algorithmicly. Perhaps somebody can file a bug report to MS?

Note that the first bug is merely a consequence (in the implementation of `equal_range`) of the second bug. Presumably, for most applications the input range is already sorted, partly because the user **sorted it unnecessarily** (demonstrating that bugs in MS's library results in bad user code), and simply providing an additional comparison operator fixes the problem (as for the OPs' question).

Answer (score 1):

[lib.equal.range] tells :

> Requires: Type T is LessThanComparable (20.1.2).

and

> Effects: Finds the largest subrange [i, j) such that the value can be
>   inserted at any iterator k in it without violating the ordering. k
>   satisfies the corresponding conditions: !(*k < value) && !(value < *k)
>   or comp(*k, value) == false && comp(value, *k) == false.

Your code satisfies both conditions and should compile fine, meaning it is a bug in visual studio.

Answer (score 1):

As a General Answer. Each compiler and standard library will have quirks and places that they do not implement the standard properly. Which means that unless the code is tested on a different platform, there is always a chance that minor changes will be required.

On the plus side, if one uses an attempt to  keep to the standard, these changes should be very minor.

Answer (score -1):

For equal range to work correctly the range need to be sorted, I think the VS compiler is trying to say that your intention is wrong, maybe?

Comment: @BЈовић yes it does, that's how it achieves O(log n) efficiency with a binary search.

Comment: @ BЈовић, how come? If the input range is not sorted the returned range may contain the values that are not part of the searched candidate.

Comment: It **doesn't** need to be sorted! See correct answer by Angew. It only needs to be partitioned w.r.t. comparison with the 3rd argument. The binary search (to get O(log n)) is still possible on the result of the partitioning, i.e. `Comp(S,2)` and/or `Comp(2,S)`. Btw, the documention given by http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/equal_range is *wrong* here.

Comment: @MarkRansom Can you tell which paragraph from the standard tells it must be sorted? Because I couldn't find any. It tells the complexity is `At most 2 * log(last - first) + 1 comparisons.`

Comment: @BЈовић But what do the results signify if it isn't sorted?  How
is "sorted" different from the explicit requirements for
`lower_bound`.  (It must be different, because the standard
requires that ranges in §25.4 be sorted, and then makes an
explicit exception for the binary search algorithms.  I just can
think of a case where a range would meet the requirements of
`lower_bound` and not be sorted.)

Comment: @Walter *was* wrong (and so were upper_bound and lower_bound)

Comment: @JamesKanze see answer by Angew for the requirement for `lower_bound` and `upper_bound`. Anyway, I tested the OP's question with the last two elements swapped, when the input range is *not sorted*, but only partitioned w.r.t. `2` (by swapping the last two entries). It compiles & produces the correct result under both gcc (4.8) and clang (3.3).

Comment: @Cubbi What do you mean *Walter was wrong*? Of course, the documentation at en.cppreference.com has been fixed by now.

Comment: @Walter, after studying Angew's answer I can see how a binary search would work with simple partitioning. As a practical matter though if you intend to search on *any* search value the range must be partitioned on every possible value, i.e. sorted.

Comment: @BЈовић see my previous comment. Although it's not required to be sorted for any particular input, it must be sorted to handle *all* inputs.

Comment: @Walter: Cubbi means "Hey Walter, cppreference is no longer wrong.", not "Walter was wrong."

Comment: @MarkRansom of course, if you want to call `std::equal_range` on several values (of the 3rd argument), then having the range sorted is the simplest (and likely most efficient) choice. But if you only want it for a few values, you may partition for each value instead of sorting it once. What is most important is that the standard (and hence any implementation) only demands the minimal requirement, i.e. partitioning.

Comment: btw take a note that the range in the question is sorted :) Therefore, it should work.

Comment: @MarkRansom Aha! It just has to be partitioned with respect to the values you actually use.  So if you have a vector of positive integers, and never search for anything but -1, the vector doesn't have to be sorted.  (Doesn't sound very useful to me.)